# Behavior of function overloading with const

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm working on g++ and here I have tried to overload a function by just adding `const` to parameter. It works fine and when it runs, it calls the function without `const`

1. Is this behavior specified in the C++ standard?
2. What the reason it calls the function without `const`

   ```
   void print(const std::string& str){std::cout << "const" << str << std::endl;}

   void print(std::string& str){std::cout << str << std::endl;}

   int main()
   {
      std::string temp = "hello";
      print(temp);
      return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: That's normal:  you don't call it with a const object.  Try with `const std::string temp = "hello"`

Comment: But if I removed second function. It automatically calls the function with `const`. so?

Comment: Well, `temp` is **not** `const`, so the second version is a better match than the first version. If you have only one version, then it is obviously the best match.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya : I have explicitly addressed your observations regarding removing the non-const version in my answer (coincidentally rather than because you asked).  But to all; can we refrain from both answering and *asking* questions in the comments?  Answers should be posted as answers, and questions arising from the OP should be added to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Reference bindings are an identity category *§13.3.3.1.4*) but since the latter is more cv-qualified, for §13.3.3.2, the non-const is preferred (sample code from the standard):

```
int f(const int &);
int f(int &);

int i;
int j = f(i); // calls f(int &)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is standard behavior. Any other behavior would lead to crazy behavior. In particular, the non-const function would not be callable at all.

Answer (score 1):

const is part of method signature. Overriding works only for methods with the same signature. 
This behavior was made to avoid reverse situation when you use const method of base class to call not const method of child class.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is this section in [over.ics.rank]/3 where this case is explicitly covered:

> Standard conversion sequence `S1` is a better conversion sequence than
>   standard conversion sequence `S2` if 
>  […] 
>  — `S1` and `S2` are reference
>   bindings (8.5.3), and the types to which the references refer are the
>   same type except for top-level cv-qualifiers, and the type to which
>   the reference initialized by `S2` refers is more cv-qualified than the
>   type to which the reference initialized by `S1` refers.

`S1` corresponds to the second overload and `S2` to the first.

> What the reason it calls the function without `const`

You always try to select the most specialized thing. That is the case in overload resolution just as it is in partial ordering of function templates. The second overload is more specialized than the first because the first can be called with arguments which the second cannot be called with - that is the basic reasoning behind this rule.

Answer (score 1):

Overloading works by matching the types of the arguments, including the qualifiers.  In your case `temp` has type `std::string` not `const std::string`.  You have only initialised it with a literal constant, it is not itself constant.

Consider the following:

```
std::string temp( "hello" ) ;
print(temp);                                    // hello   
print( std::string("hello") ) ;                 // consthello
print( "hello" ) ;                              // consthello
print( static_cast<const std::string>(temp) ) ; // consthello

const std::string temp2( "hello" ) ;
print(temp2);                                    // consthello
```

If you were to remove the non-const version, all three will call the remaining const overload.  In this example, only the const version is in fact necessary (and preferred) since neither version modify the string object.

If on the other hand you removed the non-const version, there would be no function matching any but the first example above, and the build would fail.  That is to say a non-const object can safely be passed as a const argument, but a const object cannot be passed as a non-const argument, because the function is not "promising" not to modify the object.  You can force a const into a non-const argument by a `const_cast` as in:

```
const std::string temp2("hello") ;
print( const_cast<std::string&>(temp2) ) ;    // hello
```

But if `print()` were to attempt to modify the object in this case the results are *undefined*, so consider the practice unsafe.

Making an argument const indicates intent, allows the compiler to issue a diagnostic if the code is attempts to modify the object or pass it via a non-const argument to some other function. It may also potentially provide the compiler with optimisation possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Because calling the function taking `std::string const&` requires two implicit conversions: one to `std::string const`, one to `std::string const&`; whereas calling the function taking `std::string&` requires merely one implicit conversion (to `std::string&`), so that one is preferred.

Comment: But if I removed second function. It automatically calls the function with 'const'. so?

Comment: Note how I said "preferred," not "the only possibility regardless of any other overloads that may or may not ever exist."

Comment: But the non-const function matches better. Aside from the function signature, the compiler doesn't know the non-const function doesn't actually modify the argument, so given the choice it will pick the non-const one. Without a choice, it would allow the const one to match.

Comment: It's standard behaviour.

Comment: ok, I guess copy constructor is a special case?, because there it calls the copy constructor with `const`

Comment: Not if you define a constructor `T(T&)`.